tailwind css cant render when deploy with vercel
My Simple Web Page HTML CSS can't render tailwind css when I deploy in vercel. it was used successfully during development
enter image description here
but failed not to render the CSS when in production
index.html
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="../dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

package.json
 "scripts": { "tw:run": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch" },
input.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.nav-anchor {
  @apply cursor-pointer;
}

tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

I hope the CSS can run properly when deployed
